# Need to call Matlab function from python script

Tags: python, matlab, matlab-deployment, matlab-engine

I have previously written a ~150 line MATLAB function that I wish to call from Python, instead of re-coding the entire thing into Python.

I have found a number of options online (`mlabwrap`, `matlab_wrapper`) however they are all fairly old and have all failed to install or run properly, each throwing an error.

I am running 32-bit Python 2.7.10 and 64-bit MATLAB R2013a. (btw is the fact that Python is 32-bit and MATLAB is 64-bit likely a problem?  I am fairly inexperienced regarding architecture)

What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: you can always use the official solution: [MATLAB Engine for Python](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab-engine-for-python.html)

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work when Matlab is 64 bit and python is 32 bit

Comment: use 64-bit python then.